# difference between assingment and :

Tags: oracle

what is the difference between these two ,second is arithmetic expression assigne to sal , first one is ?  how they differ exactly. if salary has intial value of 10 both result same answer. when to use them in oracle based on what  ?
if this is not a good question please disregard .

sal :=sal+300

sal=sal+300;

Comment: Justin Cave's answer is correct - but I would point out that the answer depends on which procedural language you are using.  For example, PLPGSQL the first and the second do exactly the same thing if they are a standalone statement .. but in PLSQL what Justin Cave says is 100% correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second expression is syntactically invalid (at least on its own, it could be a valid part of some other expression).

```
sal := sal + 300;
```

assigns a value to the local variable `sal` that is 300 more than the current value of that variable.

```
sal = sal + 300
```

does not change the value of `sal`.  It compares `sal` to `sal` + 300 and evaluates to a boolean.  But it would only be valid in something like an `if` statement or in a SQL statement, i.e.

```
IF( sal = sal + 300 )
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM emp
 WHERE sal = sal + 300
```

Neither of those really make sense, though, since that is, by definition, not going to evaluate to `true`.

Comment: I just want to add that in some procedural languages, the two statements are equivalent when they are stand-alone.  But for sure within a spot where a boolean evaluation would be expected, `:=` would not work. IMO, best practice would be to use Oracle pl/SQL style for `:=` and `=`.